# Horizontal histogram axis and ticks positioning

Tags: plotting, histograms

My data consists of two lists of numbers between -0.1 and 1. I would like to show them on two horizontal histograms, with a thickened x-axis. I have managed to make the first histogram look exactly like I would like:

```
Histogram[list1, Automatic, "LogCount", BarOrigin -> Left,
  PlotRange -> {-0.1, 1}, Axes -> {True, False}, Frame -> True,
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},  AxesStyle -> Thick]
```

[image: Histogram for the first list]

However, when I try to do the same thing for the second list, I get the following result:

```
Histogram[list2, Automatic, "LogCount", BarOrigin -> Left,
  PlotRange -> {-0.1, 1}, Axes -> {True, False}, Frame -> True,
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},  AxesStyle -> Thick]
```

[image: Histogram for the second list]

I am not sure why the histogram does not begin at 0. There are no negative numbers in the list so it should clearly indicate that. I can make the histogram align to the left side:

```
Histogram[list2, Automatic, "LogCount", BarOrigin -> Left,
  PlotRange -> {-0.1, 1}, Axes -> {True, False}, Frame -> True,
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 8},  AxesStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

but then the x-axis ticks are mismatched between the two histograms and I would like them to be the same.

How can I have a consistent positioning and frame ticks between the two histograms?

*Edit*: here's some example data: http://pastebin.com/raw/SzW7uiiy

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: I can't reproduce your first plot, is there any way for us to generate equivalent data to reproduce this?

Comment: @JasonB If you copy and paste the contents of http://pastebin.com/raw/SzW7uiiy to Mathematica you will see the difference. It's not as extreme as for the full data, but there is still a difference in the x-axis ticks for histograms with the same options.

Comment: @Mereenie, what version are you using?  For me (version 10.3.1), the `PlotRange` setting you use, has a horrible effect on the plots.  I have to use `PlotRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}}`  [This](http://i.imgur.com/laQsRpM.png) is what I get using your settings

Comment: But trying to manually set the `PlotRange` I get [this](http://i.imgur.com/XPZ9sYw.png) abomination

Comment: @JasonB Oh wow. I'm on 10.0.2. I wouldn't expect the settings to behave so differently between the two versions.

Comment: @Mereenie - I just tried this on version 10.1 and the `PlotRange` behaves completely differently.  I get [these](http://i.imgur.com/UPAUrkq.png) results

Comment: @Mereenie Something is still off here. I imported the data from your pastebin, and `list1` contains no negative values, but your first histogram that should represent `list1`shows that there should be roughly 400 negative values. Am I misunderstanding, or did you post a different data set?

Comment: @MarcoB, the posted data is different than that used to generate the pictures, but it does still allow to illustrate the problem, which is real.